# Error In Wade's Analysis (continuous function preserves compactness)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I would like to verify that the following proof is incorrect before raising it in another setting.
This is a proof from Wade's "An Introduction to Analysis"; I do not take issue with the theorem itself...just this particular proof of it. I will first copy the proof as stated before addressing the issue of its correctness

**Theorem**:  If $ H $ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{f}: H \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous on $H$, then $\mathbf{f} \left(H \right)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^m$

**Proof**:

Suppose $ \left\{ V_\alpha\right\}_{\alpha \in A \;} $ is an open covering of $\mathbf{f}\left(H \right)$. Then $\left\{ \mathbf{f}^{-1} \left( V_\alpha \right)\right\}_{\alpha \in A}$ covers $H$ and, by continuity, its members are relatively open in $H$ .

Thus for each $\alpha$ there exists an open set $O_\alpha$ such that $\mathbf{f}^{-1}\left( V_\alpha \right) = H \cap O_\alpha .\;$ Note that $\left\{ O_\alpha \right\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is an  open covering of $H$ and since $H$ is compact, there exists a finite subcovering $\left\{ O_{\alpha_j} \right\}^N_{j=1}$. We conclude that $$ (*) \quad \quad \quad\mathbf{f}\left( H \right) \subseteq \mathbf{f} \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^N {O_{\alpha_j} \cap H}\right) = \bigcup_{j=1}^N {\mathbf{f} \left( \mathbf{f}^{-1} \left( V_{\alpha_j}\right) \right)} = \bigcup_{j=1}^N V_{\alpha_j}$$ In particular, $\left\{ V_{\alpha_j}\right\}^N_{j=1}$ is a finite subcovering of $\mathbf{f}\left( H \right)$ and thus $\mathbf{f}\left( H \right)$ is compact.

$\\$

**The Issue**: The $\subseteq$ symbol in the line marked above by a $(*)$ is actually an equality. The author notes this in his errata, but this introduces a further problem. We now have all equalities, so that $$\mathbf{f}(H) = \bigcup_{j=1}^N V_{\alpha_j} \quad \text{i.e. compact set = union of open sets}$$

That is, the set we are claiming is compact we have also shown to be open, and this will not be true in general.

It must therefore be the case that one of the other equalities is actually a $\subseteq$. It is actually the rightmost one. Recall that the $V_{\alpha_j}$ are an open covering of the image of $\mathbf{f}, \,$ $\mathbf{f}(H).$, and will in general need to intersect its complement. That is, some of the $V_{\alpha_j}$ will contain points outside of the range of $\mathbf{f}$. For those sets $\mathbf{f} (\mathbf{f}^{-1}(V_{\alpha_j}) \neq V_{\alpha_j}$. The confusion arises because we are taking the preimage of sets that do not completely lie within the function's image. The correct sequence is as follows:

$$\mathbf{f}\left( H \right) = \mathbf{f} \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^N {O_{\alpha_j} \cap H}\right) = \bigcup_{j=1}^N {\mathbf{f} \left( \mathbf{f}^{-1} \left( V_{\alpha_j}\right) \right)} = \bigcup_{j=1}^N \left( V_{\alpha_j} \cap \text{Im}(\mathbf{f}) \right) \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N V_{\alpha_j}$$

Comment: Uhh good catch... And yes, your reasoning seems correct to me

Comment: The proof becomes much simpler if we just prove that for compact topological space $H$ and continuous map $f$ of $H$ to another topological space $X$, the image of $H$ is compact. Discussion of subspace topology and so on is not really necessary.

Comment: Does an open covering in the sense of Wade consists of open subsets of the subspace $f(H)$ (relative topology) or of open subsets of $\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: @PaulFrost that’s exactly I was thinking.

Comment: @PaulFrost He uses the term "relatively open in _" to describe the relative topology, and the term "open" will generally refer to $R^m$.

Comment: @PaulFrost The $V_\alpha$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. That is clear based on the specific form of the theorem he cites ( which states that a function will be continous if the preimage of open sets in R^m are relatively open in the domain. This text really only introduces topological concepts to the extent necessary to develop multivariate calculus.

Comment: So he does not define the concepts of topological space, subspace topology and compactness in the context of general spaces?

Comment: And, by the way, the only compact open subset of $\mathbb R^m$ is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @PaulFrost With respect to your more recent comment, that is the point that I made, in terms of alerting me to there being a problem after the subset symbol in * is corrected to an equal sign. Those cannot all be equal signs, which is when I noticed that the rightmost equality in * should be a subset symbol.

Comment: You are of course right,  "the set we are claiming is compact we have also shown to be open, and this will not be true in general."  My previous comment said that "$=$" can only be true in the only trivial case, thus "in general"  is a massive understatement.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not onto $V_a$ then $f(f^{-1}(V_a))\subseteq V_a$, so the last $=$ (equal sign) in the (*) line, is not correct.

Comment: Yes, that was my assertion. (*) is from the authors version. So you are agreeing with me I think.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.  Sorry,  I was lazy to read all of your question  , so I missed the last lines, where you do propose how to fix the  problem